# iPhone Dev > Distribute on AppStore > what versions supported?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am about to send an iPhone application to the app store, my question is: If I want my application supported by both IOS 4 and IOS 3.2... whats the plan ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the Base SDK to iOS 4.0.
- Set the Deployment Target to 3.2.
- Make sure to check for the existence of any 4.0-only features you use at runtime. Otherwise your app will crash when it runs on 3.2.

Comment: Can't emphasize enough on that last point. If possible test your app on a iOS 4 device and a iOS 3.2 one.